# No permalink in Eleventy

Tags: permalinks, eleventy

I'm migrating from Jekyll to Eleventy, where previously my blog post links had the permalink in this style: `/:title/`

> What I want: `https://example.com/my-blog-post/` for `posts/my-blog-post.md`
>
> What I get: `https://example.com/posts/my-blog-post/` for `posts/my-blog-post.md`

How can I configure this in Eleventy? The [official page](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/permalinks/) on 11ty docs says it takes the name of the folder, which is `posts` in this case.

I want this `/:title/` for all my markdown files. I can't manually set the permalink in all my files. Is there a way to do so for the entire `posts` collection?

I'm using [this repo](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-base-blog) as the base theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after searching a lot (not the docs), I finally found the solution in [this article](https://24ways.org/2018/turn-jekyll-up-to-eleventy/).

In the last part of that section, use this:

```json
// posts.json (or whatever your collection name is)
{
   // ...
   "permalink": "/{{ title | slug }}/"
   // ...
}
```

#### Excerpt:

> ### Using directory data to manage defaults
>
> By default, Eleventy will maintain the structure of your content files when generating your site. In our case, that means `/_basic-syntax/lists.md` is generated as `/_basic-syntax/lists/index.html`. Like Jekyll, we can change where files are saved using the permalink property. For example, if we want the URL for this page to be /basic-syntax/lists.html we can add the
> following:
>
> ```yaml
> ---
> title: Lists
> syntax-id: lists
> api: "no"
> permalink: /basic-syntax/lists.html
> ---
> ```
>
> Again, this is probably not something we want to manage on a file-by-file basis but again, Eleventy has features that can help: directory data and permalink variables.
>
> For example, to achieve the above for all content stored in the `_basic-syntax` folder, we can create a JSON file that shares the name of that folder and sits inside it, i.e. `_basic-syntax/_basic-syntax.json` and set our default values. For permalinks, we can use Liquid templating to construct our desired path:
>
> ```json
> {
>    "layout": "syntax",
>    "tag": "basic-syntax",
>    "permalink": "basic-syntax/{{ title | slug }}.html"
> }
> ```

Comment: For my case, alongside with `.json` file as in your solution, I have to add `permalink: "{{ title | slug }}/"` in the `_includes/layouts/post.njk` (template of the post) also.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up permalinks **per page or per collection**. Assume you create a posts folder, then add a posts.**11tydata.json** file with content to set up basic values for a collection.

```
{
  "eleventyExcludeFromCollections": false,
  "layout": "post",
  "permalink": "post/{{ title }}/",
  "tags": [
    "posts"
  ]
}
```