# How to set Eleventy URL paths that differ from their file paths

Tags: permalinks, static-site, nunjucks, eleventy

I'm building an Eleventy site and am generating blog posts from my markdown files. Unfortunately I am unable to set URL paths for these blog posts such that they differ from their file path structure. They seem to be synced in a way that I can't get around.

There is an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549284/no-permalink-in-eleventy) on SO that sums up my situation perfectly. However, the accepted solution doesn't work for me. Here's a snippet from that question:

> What I want: `https://example.com/my-blog-post/` for
> `posts/my-blog-post.md`
>
> What I get: `https://example.com/posts/my-blog-post/` for
> `posts/my-blog-post.md`

Here's a snippet from the accepted solution:

```
// posts.json (or whatever your collection name is)
{
   // ...
   "permalink": "/{{ title | slug }}/"
   // ...
}
```

This proposes updating a json file that sets global data targeting a specific collection (in this case, `posts`). While this does achieve the desired URL path of `https://example.com/my-blog-post/`, it breaks the file directory structure by removing the `posts` parent folder, causing all my `.md` files to "spill out" into the grandparent folder.

This may be a long shot, but I'm wondering if anyone has had any success with an alternative approach. I feel like this isn't too much of an edge case, as many people prefer minimal URL paths (without `/posts/` or `/blog` prefixing their pages).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by the files "spilling out" of their parent? The files in the generated site directory (`_site` by default) must reflect the URL structure. Is Eleventy overwriting your input files?

Comment: @person_v1.32 the files are "spilling out" into their grandparent folder because their parent folder is removed when I apply the fix in the code block. For example: instead of `_site/posts/my-blog-post.md`, I get `_site/my-blog-post.md`. With many posts, this could make my `_site` folder very messy.

I am basically trying to change my configuration so the URL structure does NOT match the directory structure. This way I can collect my posts in a `posts` folder without having to include `/posts/` in my URL path.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how "messy" your output `_site` folder is since you shouldn't be working in it anyway. Setting a permalink allows you to organize your input code files (in markdown) while outputting files at the root of your site. The output `_site` folder must directly reflect the URL structure of your site since this is the source and definition of your URL structure.

The only organization that matters is your input markdown files, which can be organized in a `posts/` folder. You can think of it as compiling code—the compiled output is not meant to be read by humans. Similarly, your output `_site` directory should be completely managed by Eleventy.

Now, if you *really really* want to have your output `_site` folder have a `posts` subfolder, *while also* having paths be accessible from the root of your site, you can use redirects/rewrite, which will depend on where you're hosting your site. For example, you can use [Netlify's redirects and rewrites](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/) to rewrite `https://example.com/my-blog-post/` to content in `https://example.com/posts/my-blog-post/`. However, this isn't really designed for this purpose, since your page will be accessible at both locations which can be bad for SEO and confusing for users if not done properly. Again, this is not necessary since you should not need to look into your `_site` folder besides maybe for debugging.

Comment: "It doesn't matter how "messy" your output _site folder is since you shouldn't be working in it".  This is not true. If you have duplicate filenames that "spill out" into parent folders data is going to be overwritten.

Comment: Eleventy will prevent multiple source files from writing to the same output _site location. Eleventy [should throw an error](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/permalinks/#remapping-output-(permalink)) if this happens, so pages should not be overwritten.